# spark json schema metadata can be mapped to hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, aws-glue

When working with apache spark we can easily generate a json file to describe the Dataframe structure. This dataframe structure looks as below:

```
{
  "type": "struct",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "employee_name",
      "type": "string",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {
        "comment": "employee name", 
        "system_name":  "hr system", 
        "business_key": true, 
        "private_info": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "employee_job",
      "type": "string",
      "nullable": true,
      "metadata": {
        "comment": "employee job description", 
        "system_name":  "sap", 
        "business_key": false, 
        "private_info": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When storing this information in Hive or getting the dataframe from Hive, spark will map the "comments" from the columns hive metadata to the "comment" attribute within metadata. But what about mapping the dataframe definition in a json into a Hive table, is it possible to store additional tags to the columns like business_key or private_info flag?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to store additional metadata. Create spark compatible hive table & add required metadata in `TBLPROPERTIES`

like below.

**Hive Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_details`(
  `employee_name` string COMMENT 'employee name',
  `employee_job` string COMMENT 'employee job description') 
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='orc',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"employee_name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{\"comment\":\"employee name\",\"business_key\":true,\"system_name\":\"hr system\",\"private_info\":true}},{\"name\":\"employee_job\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{\"comment\":\"employee job description\",\"business_key\":false,\"system_name\":\"sap\",\"private_info\":false}}]}'
)
```

**Accessing table from spark**

```
scala> val df = spark.table("hivedb.employee_details")
adf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [employee_name: string, employee_job: string]

scala> df.schema.prettyJson
res12: String =
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "employee_name",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : {
      "comment" : "employee name",
      "business_key" : true,
      "system_name" : "hr system",
      "private_info" : true
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "employee_job",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : {
      "comment" : "employee job description",
      "business_key" : false,
      "system_name" : "sap",
      "private_info" : false
    }
  } ]
}
```